# EclipseLink fails to create complete JoinTable for ManyToMany

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

I'm currently using EclipseLink 2.5 for a project and encountered a little problem with a ManyToMany Relation:

I have a mapped superclass `Identifiable` that defines a composite key (uuid, revision). Both Entity classes `Appointment` and `Content` are subclasses of `Identifiable`.

Now I try to define an unidirectional ManyToMany relation from `Appointment` to `Content`, but it seems that EclipseLink doesn't create the JoinTable right. There are only two columns in it (uuid, revision), but there should be four (one uuid and revision for each side of the relation).

Lust but not least, the code:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(IdentifiablePK.class)
public abstract class Identifiable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @UuidGenerator(name = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    protected String uuid;

    @Id
    protected Integer revision;

    /* ... */
}
```

```java
public class Appointment extends Identifiable {

    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "trainingcontent_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "trainingcontent_revision", referencedColumnName = "revision", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected List<TrainingContent> trainingContents;

    /* ... */
}
```

```java
public class TrainingContent extends Identifiable {
    /* ... */
}
```

I also tried to use `@JoinTable` instead of `@JoinColumns`, but then EclipseLink complains about the missing resepectively incomplete `@JoinColumns` Annotation, which is necessary for target entities with composite keys.

Am I doing something wrong?

Greetings,
chrert

Answer (score 1):

For ManyToMany you must use a @JoinTable to @JoinColumns, the source and target join columns are specified inside the @JoinTable.

Your @JoinColumn must not have, "updatable = false, insertable = false", this makes no sense, as then it would not be able to insert anything, which appears to be what is happening.

See,
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Comment: As I mentioned above, I already tried to use `@JoinTable` (joinColumns + inverseJoinColumns) instead of `@JoinColumns`, but then EclipseLink complains about the missing `@JoinColumns` Annotation. Removing the updatable, insertable doesn't work either! Btw: I also tried to replace the Many-to-Many relation by a Many-to-One, which didn't work either...